# redhat openjdk headless contents

Tags: java-8, redhat-openjdk

Is there some way to directly download the latest redhat "headless" version of JDK8?

Redhat documentation [indicates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/8/html-single/installing_and_using_openjdk_8_for_rhel/index#assembly_installing-openjdk-8-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux_openjdk):

> There is also a headless version of Java which has the smallest
> footprint and does not include the libraries needed for a user
> interface. The headless version is packaged in the headless
> subpackage.

But the Redhat OpenJDK [download](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download) page doesn't appear to include any headless versions.

Specifically, I want to see if the headless version will be sufficient to run in FIPS mode.

Comment: access.redhat.com is the Customer Portal _for RedHat's own distro_ -- RHEL = RedHat Enterprise Linux -- and has (many!) packages tailored for RHEL (and specific versions of RHEL like 7, 8, 9). These include the headless JRE, normal (headful) JRE, and JDK (named -devel). The other page you linked is RedHat's generic-for-many-systems OpenJDK build service; the Linux packages there are for any Linux not specifically RHEL and cannot assume FIPS capability because generic Linux doesn't have it. The _RHEL_ package can and I expect does but can't test because I'm not a customer.